# How to dissect/parse 'which' followed by five subordinate clauses ? (1786 UK)

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

[Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CCkvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22He+speaks+not+of+such+as+have+vowed+Chastity%22&source=bl&ots=1Ff1KL_aEw&sig=g_JuLG-41yB6k5KxqW2ZCmmApak&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cAzgVNuQJomcNtydgQg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22He%20speaks%20not%20of%20such%20as%20have%20vowed%20Chastity%22&f=false): p 174, *The Catholic Christian Instructed in the Sacraments* ...,  by [Richard Challoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Challoner), 1786

> A. Continency is not required of all, but such as 
>   have by vow engaged to keep it: and therefore, before 
>   a person engages himself by vow, he ought certainly to 
>   examine whether he has a call from God, and whether 
>   he can go through with what he thinks of undertaking : 
>   but after he has once engaged himself by vow, he is 
>   not now at liberty to go back: but may assure himself, 
>   that the gift of continence will not be denied him, so 
>   that he uses proper means to obtain and preserve it, 
>   particularly prayer and mortification, **which**, ♦  because 
>   Luther laid aside, by quitting his canonical hours of 
>   prayer and other religious exercises, to which he had 
>   been accustomed in his convent, no wonder if he had 
>   lost the gift of continency, which he owns he enjoyed 
>   whilst he was a popish friar.

I guess the bolded **which** as a relative pronoun, but despite numerous rereads, I'm lost and can't anatomise/parse the phrases after the lozenge (♦ )? Please show the steps and thought processes? This quote exemplifies [my persistent scourge](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42834/8712); I can't even determine [which is the right syntax](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm) here:

> 1. {Relative Pronoun or Adverb} + Subject + Verb   or  
>   2. {Relative Pronoun as Subject} + Verb

Comment: Published in the US a century later, I see. Retaining the archaic syntax of the original.

Answer (score 2):

I'd scan it so:

> particularly prayer and mortification, which, because Luther laid aside (, by quitting his canonical hours of prayer and other religious exercises [, to which he had been accustomed in his convent]), no wonder if he had lost the gift of continency (, which he owns he enjoyed whilst he was a popish friar).

So dropping the clauses:

> particularly prayer and mortification, which, because Luther laid *(them)* aside, *(it'd be)* no wonder if he had lost the gift of continency.

Comment: Exactly. Note that this means (as is not uncommon in older texts) that _which_ stands as a kind of dangling relative pronoun without an actual clause. In a modern text, there would almost certainly be a period instead and the next part would be turned into an actual sentence separate from the first (“Since Luther laid these aside… it is no wonder…”).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the referent of "which" is "prayer and mortification", and that "which" is the logical object of "laid aside".  So

> prayer and mortification, which, ♦ because Luther laid aside,

means:

> prayer and mortification. Because Luther laid aside prayer and mortification, ...

Answer (score -1):

The referent here of *which* is the proper **means** of obtaining and preserving the gift under discussion.

It’s saying that because Luther laid aside the means of preserving his gift, it’s no great surprise that he should have lost it.